# Multiple Arduino Boards using Johnny five

Tags: javascript, arduino, johnny-five

I am programming arduino boards in javascript. I am trying to connect multiple arduino boards using the johnny-five library. I followed the [johnny-five documentation](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/blob/master/docs/board-multi.md) and I can strobe the led 13 on both boards at once.

However my issue is I want to control leds one at a time. How can I specifically initialise LEDs on each board?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many examples in [the docs](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/wiki/Boards) for the `Boards` (note the plural) class. I've copied the following directly:

The `Boards` class constructs a collection object containing multiple board objects. If no arguments are passed, `Board` objects will be created for every board detected in the order that the system enumerates them.

See also: [Board](https://github.com/rwldrn/johnny-five/wiki/Board)

#### Parameters

- **ports** A list of port objects or port address strings. Port objects may have the following properties:

Property Name
      Type
      Value(s)
      Description
      Required
    
  
  
    
      id
      Number, String
      Any
      User definable identification
      no
    
    
      port
      String
      "/dev/ttyAM0", "COM1"
      Path or name of device port/COM
      no

#### Initializing Multiple Boards

The easiest way to initialize multiple board objects is to call the `Boards` constructor function with `new`. Don't worry about knowing your device's path or COM port, Johnny-Five will figure out which USBs are in use by compatible boards automatically.

```
// Create 2 board instances with IDs "A" & "B" 
// (ports will be initialized in device enumeration order)
new five.Boards([ "A", "B" ]);
```

Or

```
// Create two board instances on ports 
// "/dev/cu.usbmodem621" and 
// "/dev/cu.usbmodem411"
new five.Boards([ "/dev/cu.usbmodem621", "/dev/cu.usbmodem411" ]);
```

Or

```
var ports = [
  { id: "A", port: "/dev/cu.usbmodem621" },
  { id: "B", port: "/dev/cu.usbmodem411" }
];

new five.Boards(ports);
```

#### Board Ready

Once the board objects have been initialized, they must connect to the physical boards with a set of handshake steps, once this has completed, the boards are ready to communicate with the program. This process is asynchronous, and signified to the program via a "ready" event.

```
// Create 2 board instances with IDs "A" & "B"
new five.Boards([ "A", "B" ]).on("ready", function() {

  // Both "A" and "B" are initialized
  // (connected and available for communication)

});
```

Override this by providing explicit port paths:

```
var ports = [
  { id: "A", port: "/dev/cu.usbmodem621" },
  { id: "B", port: "/dev/cu.usbmodem411" }
];

new five.Boards(ports).on("ready", function() {

  // Both "A" and "B" are initialized
  // (connected and available for communication)

});
```

#### Usage

A basic, but complete example usage of the `Boards` constructor:

```
// Create 2 board instances with IDs "A" & "B"
new five.Boards([ "A", "B" ]).on("ready", function() {

  // Both "A" and "B" are initialized
  // (connected and available for communication)

  // |this| is an array-like object containing references
  // to each initialized board.
  this.each(function(board) {

    // Initialize an Led instance on pin 13 of
    // each initialized board and strobe it.
    new five.Led({ pin: 13, board: board }).strobe();
  });
});
```

Override this by providing explicit port paths:

```
var ports = [
  { id: "A", port: "/dev/cu.usbmodem621" },
  { id: "B", port: "/dev/cu.usbmodem411" }
];

new five.Boards(ports).on("ready", function() {

  // Both "A" and "B" are initialized
  // (connected and available for communication)

  // |this| is an array-like object containing references
  // to each initialized board.
  this.each(function(board) {

    // Initialize an Led instance on pin 13 of
    // each initialized board and strobe it.
    new five.Led({ pin: 13, board: board }).strobe();
  });
});
```

**NOTE** When using multiple boards, all device classes **must be initialized with an explicit reference to the board object that they will be associated to**. This is illustrated in the previous code example.

### API

**each(callback(board, index))** Call a function once for each board object.

...

One thing not currently mentioned, which I will update to do so, is that `this` inside of the `ready` handler is an array-like object containing references to each initialized board, in the order that they were created:

```
var ports = [
  { id: "A", port: "/dev/cu.usbmodem621" },
  { id: "B", port: "/dev/cu.usbmodem411" }
];

// Create 2 board instances with IDs "A" & "B"
new five.Boards(ports).on("ready", function() {

  // Both "A" and "B" are initialized
  // (connected and available for communication)

  this[0]; // <-- this is board A reference
  this[1]; // <-- this is board B reference

});
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could access each board using their `id`s. Or you can instantiate two boards with different names such as:

```
var five = require("johnny-five"),
    boardNumberOne = new five.Board();
    boardNumberTwo = new five.Board();
```